# I am getting fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled in Azure Pipelines

Tags: bash, git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a repository on GitHub and another in Azure DevOps. I want changes made on GitHub to be reflected in my Azure DevOps Repo automatically. First, I set up the repositories. While importing my GitHub Repo into Azure DevOps, I entered my GitHub Personal Access Token information as a variable. I also added a cron job to the pipeline. However, I am encountering errors in the pipeline. What might I have missed? Thank you in advance for your responses.

```
name: Sync Github to Azure Devops Repo

trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: "* * * * *"
  displayName: 
  branches:
    include:
    - '*' 

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |
    git clone --mirror https://github.com/<GitHubUsername>/<RepositoryName>.git
    cd <RepositoryName>
    git remote set-url --push origin "https://<DevOpsUsername>:$(GitHubToken)<@DevOpsOrganizationURL>/<DevOpsProjectName>/<RepositoryName>"
    git push --mirror
  displayName: 'GitHub Repo Sync'
```

I'm getting these errors in this AzureDevOps Pipline. What could be the causes of my error thank you

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com / /not found

##[error]Bash exited with code '128'.
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs when Git attempts to authenticate with a remote repository using HTTPS, but it fails to prompt you for your username. The root cause is often related to incorrect or missing Git credentials. You need to set the git configuration.

In your scenario, you need to set your `user.name` and `user.email` using the following commands:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your@email.com"
```

Per your requirement, you need to Sync Github repo to Azure DevOps Repo. You can follow below steps to do that.

1. Install the extension [Shell exec task without file](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tsuyoshiushio.shell-exec&targetId=a4a44a25-6aa7-417e-8b34-1dc5dfc4e294&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) which can execute commands which your write on the Task.
2. Grant the build service account (`Project Collection Build Service (xxx)`) permission to push changes to the target repo (Azure DevOps repo).

   Go to **Project Settings** -> **Repositories** (`https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{Project}/_settings/repositories`) -> Select the target repo (Azure DevOps repo) -> **Security** -> Search the build service account (`Project Collection Build Service (xxx)`) - Grand the following permissions to it:

   - Contribute
   - Create branch (The sync actions will sync all branches; it may need to create branches during the sync actions)
   - Create tag
   - Force push (rewrite history, delete branches and tags) (If the git objects are not in the same line between the repos, we need to force push to target repo)
   - Read
3. Create a pipeline in your Azure DevOps, and select "**GitHub**"
   [image]
4. Enter your GitHub credential to Auth.

[image]

4. Set the YAMl pipeline like the following. It will sync all branches from GitHub to Azure DevOps repo.

```
name: Sync Github to Azure Devops Repo

trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: "* * * * *"
  displayName: 
  branches:
    include:
    - '*' 

variables:
  system_accesstoken: $(System.AccessToken)

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: true
  
- task: shellexec@0
  inputs:
    code: |
      git config --global user.email "xx@xx.com"
      git config --global user.name "xxx"
      git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
      git remote add vsts https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{Project}/_git/{RepositoryName}
      git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(system_accesstoken)" push -u vsts "${remote#origin/}"; done
```

Comment: According to the [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name), `user.name` (and `user.email`) has no effect on authentication.  This is an authentication problem, and thus those values aren't relevant.